# Prevent presenting of variable in cmake GUI

Tags: visual-studio, build-process, cmake

I want to limit hard-coded **CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES** to **RELEASE** and **DEBUG** only. If I execute cmake GUI on Windows to create Visual Studio build, CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES is present along with other cmake variables.

How can I remove CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES from the GUI?

Thanks
Dima

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`MARK_AS_ADVANCED`](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#command:mark_as_advanced) command:

```
MARK_AS_ADVANCED( CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES )
```

Also, remember that in order to change the configuration types, you need to set it **before** the `PROJECT()` command.